# How can I add plain HTML form input to Joomla frontend article submission override and save to DB _content ~ attribs table?

Tags: joomla3.0, jform

I created a frontend override of `com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php` and added a plain ol' HTML input field within the `<form>` as below:

```html
<input type="text" name="jform[attribs][vidurl]" value="" id="jform_attribs_vidurl" />
```

I expected the data to be saved in the `_content/attribs` table but it just returns null as if the name is not passed during `POST`.

### It worked properly for the image field

I did the same for the `image_intro` field and that value saves correctly.

I deleted line

```php
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('image_intro', 'images'); ?>
```

and used

```html
<input type="hidden" name="jform[images][image_intro]" id="jform_images_image_intro" value="" />
```

Then pass the image path value from a **AJAX** process after successful upload via file input field, to the hidden image field via javascript. The data saves successfully on submit.

#### Is it that there must be an existing XML string with the field attributes?

Does `JFORM` ignore HTML fields if its attributes are not found in a `xml` string? **How can I get a custom added field to save?**

#### The custom form output

[image: joomla custom frontend article submission form]

Comment: I couldn't define any method to achieve the goal so I just developed a custom content submission form by creating a new views template in `com_content/views/postform` and used the **Table()** API to store the entries. With this method I can add as many customized fields needed for frontend use.

Comment: This question is different from https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31416/12352, right?  If so, would you like to ask it on JSE?  Did you resolve it?

Comment: @mickmackusa this was long resolved since Aug '21. I had written a function to do the process, along with other actions.

Comment: Might you answer or delete this abandoned question? (Of course, I'd rather see it on JSE.)

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't know how to move the post to JSE, that may be an action by an administrator. 
The process I defined was rather extensive as it completely replaced the core Joomla front article submission form with an entirely custom set of fields added as override to `site/components/com_content/views/postform`, and configured by an associated system plugin. The submission is then mapped to the `_content` table and other associated tables. Similar to what formbuilders like RSForm does.  I didn't post it as an answer because it became quite complex and didn't seem relative to question.

Comment: No worries.  For your information, any page that is less than 6 months old can be migrated by SO volunteer moderators (upon request via custom flag.  Since I am a moderator on JSE, my migration request flags are expedited).  After that, it takes a paid employee from Stack Overflow headquarters to do the migration.  If you do not intend to self-answer the question, I might urge you to delete it.  If you'd like to answer it, perhaps you'd like to delete this page, then ask&answer at JSE.  Totally up to you.